# How to Convert a Vector to a Number in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a vector, A=[2 2 4 5]. I want to convert A to a number. Answer should be 2245.

Example 2. B=[5,6,7,8,9]. Answer should be 56789.

Thanks.

PS. Thanks to all. Now I understand to convert the vector to a string and delete the space, and convert back to a number.

Comment: What if numbers are greater than 10?

Comment: This sounds like a fun experiment to play with, but your question is likely to get downvotes unless you can demonstrate more thought and effort applied to the problem so far. What are your initial thoughts on how this should work? What is preventing you from completing it in Matlab specifically? Can you solve it in Javascript or C or your favorite language?

Comment: I'm new to Matlab. Just a beginner. I don't have any programming experience so I'm learning as I go.

Comment: like C= [2 3 10]? Answer should be 2310.

Comment: @timrow - You're welcome.  You can help even more by accepting one of our answers.  This signifies to the StackOverflow community that you no longer need any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this -

```
>> a = [2 3 10];
>> str2num(strrep(num2str(a), ' ', ''))
ans =
    2310
```

Why does it work? Well, `num2str` ("number to string") converts the vector into its character representation

```
>> num2str(a)
ans =
    2   3   10
```

which is almost what you want, except for the spaces between the numbers. So you call `strrep` ("string replace") to replace all the spaces (`' '`) with the empty string (`''`)

```
>> strrep('hi there', ' ', '')
ans =
    hithere
```

and finally use `str2num` ("string to number") to convert the resulting string back into a number.

Comment: You probably want to turn the string back to a number as well.

Comment: Ah, I missed that he wanted a numeric result. I'll add that! (+1 on your answer btw, it's a bit more full-featured than mine - although I prefer to do everything in a single expression if it's still easy to understand).

Comment: lol np.  BTW, I was in the middle of writing about `strrep` when you answered it for me.  d'oh.  BTW, +1.

Answer (score 3):

Take each number, convert it to a string and concatenate the results.  Take this string and convert it back into a number.  You can use [`num2str`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html) on the array, remove any white spaces that result from this conversion using [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) then convert the string back to a number with [`num2str`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html):

```
C = [2 3 10];
strC = num2str(C);
strC(ismember(strC, ' ')) = [];
out = str2num(strC)

out = 

2310
```

Alternatively, you can use [`strrep`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strrep.html) to replace all spaces with nothing after you run `num2str`, then convert back to a number:

```
C = [2 3 10];
strC = num2str(C);
strC = strrep(strC, ' ', '');
out = str2num(strC)

out = 

2310
```

Tipping the hat to Chris Taylor, this can all be done in one line:

```
out = str2num(strrep(num2str(C), ' ', ''))

out = 

2310
```

---

One more for academic purposes is to use regular expressions.  Specifically, use [`regexprep`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html) on the converted string array that is output from `num2str` and replace all spaces with nothing:

```
C = [2 3 10];
strC = num2str(C);
out = str2num(regexprep(strC, '\s*', ''))

out = 

2310
```

The pattern `\s*` searches for 0 or more white space characters.  We find these and set them to nothing.

Comment: @LuisMendo - I tried this on `C = [2 3 10];`, the result I get is a two element vector that contains `[2,310]`: `str2num(num2str([2 3 10], '%i'))`

Comment: @rayryend Yeah, I thought numbers could only be smaller than 10. Sorry!

Comment: @LuisMendo - No problem my friend :) BTW, your approach with numerics only is very nice. +1 for you there.

Comment: It _was_ nice when I thought the numbers were only 0, ..., 9. Now it's a little stretched :-)

Answer (score 3):

*Thanks to [@obchardon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4363864/obchardon) for a correction.*

This uses only arithmetics (no strings). It works for numbers greater than `0`. `A` can be a row or column vector.

```
A = [2 0 3 10];
x = cumsum(floor(log10(A.'+(A.'==0)))+1);
x = x(end)-x;
result = A(:).'*10.^x
```

which gives

```
result =
       20310
```

Comment: But it will fail for `log10(0)`. `cumsum(floor(log10(A.'+(A.'==0)))+1)` can be used for robustness

Answer (score 1):

If you want to string all of the digits together like they are the digits in a single integer you can convert the vector to a string, remove the spaces to smoosh the digits together, and then convert it back to a single number.

This way will handle an arbitrary number of digits in each vector element (assuming they are all real integers) rather than trying to multiply each element by the respective power of 10 and taking the sum.

Example code:

```
A = [2 44 12 6];
Astr = num2str(A);
Astr(strfind(Astr, ' ')) = [];
Anum = str2double(Astr);
```

Answer (score 1):

This uses `num2str` without having to worry about whitespaces.
Apply `num2str` to every number using `arrayfun`, con`cat`enate the resulting strings, convert back to number. Sadly it is quite a bit slower than the whitespace-deleting or numerical approach.

```
numStrings = arrayfun(@num2str,a,'uni',0);
out = str2num(cat(2,numStrings{:}))
out =
        2310
```